# Mirror modifier distort ambient occlusion texture on mirror axis

Tags: modeling, mirror

My ambient occlusion texture appears to be black at the centre of the mirror. Clipping at the centre is correct. What might be the problem?

[image]

Comment: I noticed that this problem goes away when subdivision surface modifier is used. But since I want low poly I don't want to use any such modifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is not the mirror modifier but the Subdivision Surface modifier.
It has a checkbox `Subdivide UVs` which is enabled by default.

If it was enabled during baking it can create this kind of black seams if you

- delete the subsurf modifier
- do not display the subsurf modifier
- lower the subdivision level
- or disable `Subdivide UVs` afterwards

I guess you want a low poly character with smooth AO, so you probably deleted the subsurf modifier. In this case you should just deactivate `Subdivide UVs` during baking.

Comment: Thank You. It was indeed the subdivision surface modifier issue.